# Building and installing Perl subsystem in a project that uses make (Makefile)

Tags: perl, build, installation, makefile

What build system (make, [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker), [Module::Build](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild), ...) to use in a Perl subsystem (e.g. Perl bindings, or an auxillary command implemented in Perl), and how to connect it to build system of the main project.  The project itself uses **make** as a build system.  Perl subsystem is in a separate subdirectory.

We can assume that if there is Perl installed, then it is at least version 5.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 5.8 EUMM is okay. Connect it to the main Makefile the straight-forward way, write a `perl-binding` target which just contains the [usual incantation](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#Default_Makefile_Behaviour).

Comment: How to organize this so that `$(MAKE) -C perl-dir` in main Makefile works?

Comment: Write a seperate Makefile.fromparent so that it does not collide with the Makefile from the Perl toolchain. Call it with `-f` in addition to `-C`.